# iOS IBoutlet is Unavailable Compilation error

Tags: ios, iboutlet

I'm getting these lots of error while compilation .
You help would be highly appreciated .

All these UI component are defined as IBoutlet in header file.

Thanks

[Please check screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE4Um.png)

Comment: So show us the header file in wuestion

Comment: @DuncanC here is header file 

http://prntscr.com/bwngah

Comment: From the image you posted, all the variables that gives you an error are not correctly configured: in the image you provided, they doesn't have the filled dot but they have an empty one.
Are you sure they are correctly configured in the xib? Can you provide an image of you xib's connections?

Answer (score 0):

If your outlets were created successfully, just try to refer to it this way `self.YourOutlet` or `[self.YourOutler someMethod:parameter1];`

Comment: I'm not using property to make Iboutlets so no need to use self.Outlet

Comment: @AnkitWadhw, I understood this as soon as you posted your second screenshot. Otherwise, I just test it for myself, and everything works properly. May be you forget about header file?

Comment: It was working fine for me as well 2-3 months back, but it started getting lot of error like Iboutlet is unavailable .

Comment: @AnkitWadhw, do you try to clean and rebuild project ? Or, may be it occurs only on new Xcode version. Because I tested it on 7.3

Comment: I'm using XCode 7.3 too and i did clean build folder restated xcode but nothing seems to be working ..

Comment: @AnkitWadhw, well could you provide more info ?